# QML Screen incorrect properties at application start up

Tags: qt, screen, qml, screen-size

I need correct screen sizes at start but if i do this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Rectangle {

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log( Screen.height, Screen.width, Screen.desktopAvailableHeight, Screen.desktopAvailableWidth);
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log( Screen.height, Screen.width, Screen.desktopAvailableHeight, Screen.desktopAvailableWidth);
    }
}
```

i have zeros at start
and correct screen sizes at mouse click

```
0 0 0 0
1200 1920 1133 1920
```

How can tell what is this?
And how i can get correct screen sizes at start of application?

Answer (score 2):

Currently I'm solving the similar issue. 
From [Screen documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html):

> Note that the Screen type is not valid at `Component.onCompleted`,
>   because the `Item` or `Window` has not been displayed on a screen by this time

So you won't be able to use `onCompleted()` to get the screen size from Screen item.
But instead you can get this info from C++ side of the app and pass to QML context:

```
QScreen* screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QSize screenSize = screen->size();
QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
QQmlContext* qmlContext = viewer.rootContext();
qmlContext->setContextProperty("screenSize", screenSize);
```

Comment: Yep, i tried this one too, and in this case faced with problem that any variable i set is not defined in main Component.onCompleted. Looks like it definition happens later. For now i have some dirty hack. I wait until Screen.height and Screen.width != 0 and then dynamically create qml objects.

Comment: Can you describe your task in more details? What are you trying to create in onCompleted?

Comment: i have game with qml-box2d, and at start i need to calculate scale by screen sizes, but screen sizes zeros so scale zero and when box2d object creates they have zero sizes, and game crush on box2d assert

Comment: Now i solve this with: 
       onScaleChanged: {
        if( scale == 0)
            return;

        //create box2d objects
    }